# WPF, multiple versions of third-party control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, redirect, .net-assembly

I have a WPF application, which utilizes various third-party controls in numerous projects.  In one of these projects, I need to upgrade a particular control to the latest version, while leaving the other projects grid control intact with the earlier version.  Can anyone recommend articles, sample code, etc., which shows how to do this?  Simply put, I need to do something like this:

- MainAppModule.csproj, references and deploys all shared dll's to ...\lib folder

  - ModuleA.csproj, references ThirdParty.dll, v1.0
  - ModuleB.csproj, references ThirdParty.dll, v2.0

Is assembly binding redirect what is needed here?  If so how would it be set up?

Comment: *"while leaving the other projects grid control intact with the earlier version"* is hard for me to parse. You might be able to just put `xmlns:xxx="blah blah"` for different values of "blah blah" on differing child controls, but you'll have to be a little more concrete about what you're trying to do here. The one absolutely unambiguous way to communicate what your XAML is doing is to show us your XAML. That's the gold standard for dealing with guys like me who want more clarification. The only adequate description of code is the code itself.

Comment: If the assemblies in question are strong named there should not be a problem with multiple versions of the same control in the same process

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you mean by assembly-binding-redirect...

And i am not really sure if this works for you since both assemblies will have the *same* namespace...

But you can try it with a custom [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx). This event handler is called when a `class` or `struct` is about to be created or used and the assembly of this type is currently not availiable.
So, first you have to move those assemblies out of the default resolution path of your project so this event handler will be called. When its called you know that one of those two versions is needed and by looking at [ResolveEventArgs.Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resolveeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll know which version is required. Then you load this assembly and return it from the event handler.

Be sure to check that the event handler is called exactly twice so that both versions are loaded...

Comment: That would only work in the scenario where the assemblies are not strong named and you are using multiple AppDomains. Speaking generally, you would need another AppDomain as .NET won't load what it considers to be the same assembly twice in the same AppDomain if the assemblies are not strong named, even if you use a handler.   Using child AppDomains for UI components is probably not a good idea due to the .NET remoting involved.